# Keeping labels for tick marks on a graph using pgfplots the same distance from x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have labels for two tick marks.  One of the labels, `-8`, is to be surrounded by white space so that it gives the appearance of being typeset over the graph.  I do this with the following commands.

```
extra x ticks={-8},
extra x tick style={ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, inner xsep=10pt, fill=white}},
extra x tick labels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}8},
```

There is too much white space, though.  What is the default distance between the center of the node and the sides?  I would like either two-thirds this distance or half the distance.  How do I decrease the dimensions of the box containing `-8` and the white space while maintaining consistency of distances between the labels `-8` and `8` and their respective tick marks?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}



\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}



\begin{axis}[width=3.5in, height=3.5in, axis lines=middle, axis on top, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    ymin=-2.5,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-2.5:10,
    xtick={8}, ytick={8},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
    xticklabels={8},
    extra x ticks={-8},
    extra x tick style={ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, inner xsep=10pt, fill=white}},
    extra x tick labels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}8},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[samples=2, blue, domain=-10:0] {x + 8} node [anchor=south east, pos=0.35, font=\footnotesize] {$y= \vert x \vert + y = 8$};
\addplot[samples=2, blue, domain=0:10] {-x + 8};

\addplot[dashed, latex-latex, domain=-2.5:10] (6,x) node [pos=0.9, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$x=6$};

\coordinate (A) at (6,0);
\coordinate (B) at (6,2);
\coordinate (C) at (0,8);
\coordinate (D) at (-8,0);

\end{axis}

\fill[gray!50, fill opacity=0.25] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the vertical distance here, the default value of the `inner sep`, which is the distance from the node content to the node border, is `0.333em` in both `x` and `y` directions.

It may not be a surprise that the vertical padding is set with `inner ysep`, similar to `inner xsep` which sets the horizontal padding.

If you reduce that the node label will move up a bit, but you can shift it downwards to take that into account with `yshift`. So for example, add `inner ysep=0.15em,yshift=-0.183em` to your `ticklabel style. 0.333-0.15=0.183, hence the values.

Comment: I am guessing what you mean by "node content" is "the smallest rectangle containing the node content" and so the default distance between this rectangle and the node border is `0.333em`.

Comment: I have the tick label `8` typeset using the default values.  The `8` is typeset a certain distance below the `x`-axis.  `-8` is to be typeset with less vertical spacing between `-8` and the top and bottom edges of the border.  In particular, it is to be decreased from the default `0.333em` to `0.15em`.  To get  `-8` the same distance below the `x`-axis  as `8`, it has to be shifted downward by `0.333dm - 0.15em = 0.183em`.

Comment: @Adelyn Ehm,  yes, that looks about right I think.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is using a `\colorbox` for the extra tick label:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\newcommand\whitebg[2][2pt]{{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{#1}%
    \raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height-#1\relax][\dimexpr\depth-#1\relax]{\colorbox{white}{#2}}%
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=3.5in, height=3.5in,
    axis on top,
    clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    ymin=-2.5,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-2.5:10,
    xtick={8}, ytick={8},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
    xticklabels={8},
    extra x ticks={-8},
    extra x tick style={ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize}},
    extra x tick labels={\whitebg{\makebox[2em]{\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}8}}},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[samples=2, blue, domain=-10:0] {x + 8}
    node [anchor=south east, pos=0.35, font=\footnotesize] {$y= \vert x \vert + y = 8$};
\addplot[samples=2, blue, domain=0:10] {-x + 8};
\addplot[dashed, latex-latex, domain=-2.5:10] (6,x)
    node [pos=0.9, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$x=6$};

\coordinate (A) at (6,0);
\coordinate (B) at (6,2);
\coordinate (C) at (0,8);
\coordinate (D) at (-8,0);
\end{axis}
\fill[gray!50, fill opacity=0.25] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]